# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.3.1 while creating a new project in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a new project but it getting following error .
I am using python 2.6
and django 1.3.0

```
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.3.1
```

Comment: Do you have two or more different versions of Django installed?

Comment: perhaps no i am not sure while checking it i am getting only one i.e 1.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have both Django 1.3.0 and 1.3.1 installed and you're using the `django-admin.py` from Django 1.3.1 while having Django 1.3.0 in your default Python path.

Try either of:

1. Using the correct version of `django-admin.py` corresponding to the Django version in your Python path (the one inside the `bin/` directory of your Django 1.3.0 installation).

   You can check where your correct `django-admin.py` script is by executing this:

   `echo "$(dirname $(python -c "import django; print django.__file__"))/bin/django-admin.py"`
2. Getting your Python path to correctly point to your Django 1.3.1 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting easy_install.pth file if you try to install using easy_install too.

I have this issue as pip didn't worked i tried with easy_install and it installed the latest django, so have to delete it that file from dist-packages folder. Hope this helps some one referring.