# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.8.3 in Django 1.9

Tags: django

I use Django 1.9 after updating of Django 1.8, and when i type command

```
django-admin runserver
```

I got this one error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.8.3
```

And then I try to type this one command:

```
django-admin.py runserver
```

I got this one error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 12, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 26, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 27, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I try uninstall and install Django. But i still have this errors. Hope somebody can help me with it. Thanks

Comment: Did you use both `pip` and `easy_install` to manage your packages? If yes, then answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200056/pip-broke-how-to-fix-distributionnotfound-error) may be of some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't normally use `django-admin`, except when you do `django-admin startproject`.

After you have created the project, it is easier to use `manage.py` to run the dev server, because it takes care of setting the path and settings module for you.

```
./manage.py runserver
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used another python version? It is python 2.7 now, and it seems you don't installed django properly for python2.7. You can try

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

for using python3 in ubuntu (it is installed by default and accessibler with `python3`), or try to define how to run it with another python version.

Comment: When i try to `python3 manage.py run server`, i got `ImportError: No module named 'django'`

Comment: Well, i failed. Then you can try to determine if it is installed coorectly, and first of all check your env variables. There's one close question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712371/pkg-resources-distributionnotfound-django-1-3-1-while-crating-a-new-project-in. Try it and tell if it solve you problem