# Error "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.9" when startproject

Tags: django

I have a problem when i try to create new project. It happens after updating Django from 1.8 version to 1.9. So when i use command:

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

i've got error:

```
CommandError: /var/www/myproject/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files
```

when i type this command:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

i've got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.9
```

So according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712582/4592608), i check the path of django-admin.py and check the django, and it the same. I tried to delete and install django using pip, but i've got still the same error.

I will be glad if somebody help me with that. Thank You!

Comment: Why are you trying to start your project again if all you've done is upgrade django?...

Comment: I have the folder with another projects. And im this folder i try to do it